# How to determine in Android how to get if statement working using ListView,Hashmap, & item.get(...)?

Tags: java, android, listview, if-statement, hashmap

I am somewhat of a beginner to Android (somewhat), and I am having a problem adapting code to my use. I've gotten everything **except** the if statement. Which is sad, because that's a rather basic thing.

I'm parsing a JSON file, and outputting it's results into a ListView using a Hashmap. So far, so good. I want to put an AlertDialog as one of the String "put"s of the Hashmap. Fine.

However, I now want to check that if the title (which is in the map) ends in ".pdf", to do a different action *rather* than displaying the AlertDialog.

Code:

```
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) { HashMap<String, String> item = (HashMap<String, String>)     
parent.getItemAtPosition(position);
String theTitle = item.get("title");
String theDesc = item.get("description");
String theLink = item.get("link");
if (???condition???) {
      //code I already have
} else {
    final AlertDialog.Builder hope = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
    hope.setTitle("Description");
    hope.setMessage(theDesc);
    hope.setPositiveButton("DISMISS",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
            }});

    hope.setNegativeButton("",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
         public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            dialog.dismiss();
        }});
    hope.show();
}
```

Any, and all, help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .contains method if your title have the full path like this.

```
if(theTitle.contains(".pdf")){
     //Do something
}
```

I hope this answer your query.

Comment: Wow. Just wow. I tried all sorts of solutions for over an hour, and suddenly this works. Thank you!

Comment: Youre welcome. If this answer does help you, please accept it.

Comment: Done. is it really that bad a question that I got a -2? I literally tried **many** different expressions before asking (most of which came from this site, in fact). Even a different version of this: theTitle.matches("(?i).*pdf.*")

Comment: No, it is not. Some people just dont understand how does it feel to get stuck at things. Hours and days passby and it isn't working and in the end when you get really frustrated and desperate you turn to stackoverflow for help where you meet these people. These things are normal.